# Performing a HTTP POST request in Node with MongoDB/Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have defined my schema, I just need to know the syntax to do the actual HTTP POST request. I am using MongoDB with Mongoose framework. This way when I go to my localhost:300/users I can see my JSON data posted.

The JSON data I want to post to my localhost:3000/users

```js
{ 
  "firstName": "Jono", 
  "lastName": "Ganesan", 
  "email": "user@example.com", 
  "username": "username", 
  "password": "password" 
}
```

my server.js file

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var mongoose = require('./config/mongoose');
var express = require('./config/express');
var db = mongoose();
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

user.server.model.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

user.server.routes.js

```js
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.route('/users').post(users.create);
};
```

user.server.controller

```js
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        } else {
            res.json(user);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, what exactly you want here? Do you want code to make server call on client side using javascript, angular etc?

Answer (score -1):

As I understood - you want to know the syntax of making post request to add user.
On client side, using jQuery - you can make a server POST request using this code:

```
$.post("http://localhost:300/users", { 
  "firstName": "Jono", 
  "lastName": "Ganesan", 
  "email": "user@example.com", 
  "username": "username", 
  "password": "password" 
} ,
 function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data);
});
```

Comment: in respect to my user.server.model.js file for userchema

Comment: Node is just Javascript with exact same syntax. Also, Node code cant run on client side, so I would like to see some explanation regarding what exactly is question.

Comment: this tutorial shows how to output JSON data from the database to localhost. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5e1NEdfs4is

Comment: I would like to do the same using their node/mongodb/mongoose syntax.

Comment: you need to install a library to use jQuery in node with `npm install package` make sure you're in the same directory when you run the install. I use node-fetch for this, so i'd have to `cd` to that directory and then `npm install node-fetch` and then i'd have to declare that I want to use node-fetch in my nodes app.js file by writing at the top `const fetch = require('node-fetch');` which would then allow me to `fetch();` below.